# How do I query a search result in flask-sqlalchemy 3.0?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is how I created the query in flask-sqlalchemy 2.0.

```
search_results  = Posts.query.filter(Posts.content.like('%'post_searched_form + '%')).order_by(Posts.title).all()
```

How would I create the query above in flask-sqlalchemy 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

contains still works well for me. In your case it would be something like this

`search_results = Posts.query.filter(Posts.content.contains(post_searched_form).order_by(Posts.title).all()`

You can check out [Sqlachemy contains](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.contains) here to understand better.

Note: it is also case sensitive